# How to get square of numpy.sin() in a function?

Tags: python, function, numpy

I want to compute the integral of sin^2(x) over the range [0 to 2pi] with `midpoint_rule` function. The code can computing the sin(x) with this parameters `print(midpoint_rule(np.sin,0,2*np.pi,1000))` but when i change `np.sin` to this `np.sin**2` i get the error on the bottom. What should i do for fix this?

```
def midpoint_rule(f,a,b,num_intervals):
    """
        integrate function f using the midpoint rule
        
        Args:
        f: function to be integrated
        a: lower bound of integral range
        b: upper bound of integral range
        num_intervals: the number of intervals in [a,b]
      
        Returns:
        compute the integral
    """
    
    L = (b-a) #how big is the range
    dx = L/num_intervals #how big is each interval
    midpoints = np.arange(num_intervals)*dx+0.5*dx+a
    integral = 0
    
    for point in midpoints:
        integral = integral + f(point)
    return integral*dx

print(midpoint_rule(np.sin**2,0,2*np.pi,1000))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-a71b452963dc> in <module>
     26     return integral*dx
     27 
---> 28 print(midpoint_rule(np.sin**2,0,2*np.pi,1000))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'numpy.ufunc' and 'int'
```

Comment: `np.sin` is a function, you can use, for instance: `np.sin(range(5, 10))` you have to give input to the function.

Comment: You have to make a new function. You could use a `lambda` for this. For example, `lambda x: np.sin(x) ** 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the problem, you want to pass `np.sin` as a function, my suggestion is to use `np.sin` instead of `f`, and completely remove `f`.

```
for point in midpoints:
    integral = integral + np.sin(point) ** 2
return integral * dx
```

Then print the function

```
print(midpoint_rule(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000))
```

Output:

```
3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function does the job.

```py
import numpy as np

def midpoint_rule(f,a,b,num_intervals):
    """
        integrate function f using the midpoint rule
        
        Args:
        f: function to be integrated
        a: lower bound of integral range
        b: upper bound of integral range
        num_intervals: the number of intervals in [a,b]
      
        Returns:
        compute the integral
    """
    
    L = (b-a) #how big is the range
    dx = L/num_intervals #how big is each interval
    midpoints = np.arange(num_intervals)*dx+0.5*dx+a
    integral = 0
    
    for point in midpoints:
        integral = integral + f(point)
    return integral*dx

print(midpoint_rule(lambda x: np.sin(x)**2,0,2*np.pi,1000))
```